# MeteorJS: accessing window global scope in server

Tags: meteor

I have a small app that has a file called cities.js. This file has a variable like so:

`window.cities = ["city a", "city b", "city c"];`

How do you access the window object in MeteorJS if you are executing server-side? Or how can I load in this file so that the `window.cities` variable will be available?

The error I keep getting is `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Here is my code (server.js):

```
  Meteor.startup(function(){
    if(Cities.find().count() === 0) {
      len = window.cities.length;
      for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        c = window.cities[i];
        c = c.split(", ").join("+");
        Citites.insert({city_name: c})
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: You can't. `window` is a variable referring to the browser window of the client and this is not in any way part of `meteor`'s namespace. You will need to save your data into a collection while on the client, which you can then read on the server.

Comment: since that seemed to be what you were looking for, I made my comment into an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `window` is a variable referring to the browser window of the client and this is not in any way part of meteor's namespace. You will need to save your data into a collection while on the client, which you can then read on the server.